# Azure servicetags - connecting to Powerautomate

Tags: azure, power-platform, azure-nsg

I have created an nsg in my test environemnt in azure because i have an MySQL server and a private endpoint. I can connect to my MySQL ok on a VM living within the same subnet (so thats great) but i need it to be available in Power Automate. I have read that I can use Servicetags within my nsg so I can connect to the powerplatform but i cannot seem to get it correct , plus I dont know if I can use Power authomate within the power platofrm with a service tag. Has anyone done anything like this before ? I am looking at creating a connection within Power Automate using the MySQL information.

[image]

As you can see i have added it as outbound and inbound and allowed all just for testing. So I can lock it down later.

Any help would be amazing